# Potential inside a Charged Conductor near another Charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, conductors

Let's say that we have a solid conducting sphere with radius *r* and this conductor is given a positive charge of *q<sub>1</sub>*. We know that the charge will get distributed on the surface to reduce field inside to *|**E**|=0* (by Gauss's Law). 
 Now another positive charge, say *q<sub>2</sub>*, has been taken from infinity to a certain distance *D* from the center of this sphere. We know that due to polarization, charge density on the spherical surface might redistribute itself depending on how further *q<sub>2</sub>* is from the sphere. We also know that potential inside this sphere will be same throughout. 
 My question is: What will be the potential inside the sphere with respect to infinity?

Comment: The potential  inside will be the same as it was before the new charge came in